# Django ImageField with tempfile

Tags: django, file, testing, model

Folks, I need help understanding some details about how Django saves model files. I've written a test that involves creation of files (in a temporary directory via [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html)) and has the following lines:

```
TEMP_DIR = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
TEMP_DIR_PATH = TEMP_DIR.name
...

@override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=TEMP_DIR_PATH)
def create_photo(self, album_number, photo_number):
    ...
    p = Photo.objects.create(
        number=photo_number,
        album=album,
        added_by=self.user,
        image=SimpleUploadedFile(
            name=...,
            content=open(..., 'rb').read(),
            content_type='image/jpeg'
        ),
        remarks='-'
    )
    p.full_clean()
    p.save()
    return p
```

This code works, except for one thing that confuses me. The line `p = Photo.objects.create` causes a file to appear in the temporary directory. Then `p.full_clean()` does nothing to the file. However when I execute `p.save()`, the file disappears from the temporary directory. If I remove `p.save()`, the file stays there when the function returns.

So my test function

```
def test_image_file_present(self):
    """When a photo is added to DB, the file actually appears in MEDIA."""
    p = self.create_photo(3, 2)
    image_filename = p.image.file.name
    if not os.path.exists(image_filename):
        self.fail('Image file not found')
```

fails if `p.save()` is there but passes if I remove `p.save()`.

Why would `object.save()` cause the file to disappear?

As a bonus question, what's the purpose of `.save()` if the file and the Django model object appear already during `Photo.objects.create`? I've checked that the `pre-save` signal is sent by `Photo.object.create()` as well as by `p.save()`.

Comment: I'm hesitant to answer because I don't know why your image is deleting when you run .save() - my guess is you have overriden the clean() method on the model and maybe there is some other code causing a bug between the creation of the model, and then trying to save it again after performing full_clean(). However without the code I can't be sure. The purpose of .save() is if you want to perform some actions before you actually save the instance. You can do the exact same thing without using the `Model.objects` by doing 
`p = Photo(...args) 
p.full_clean()
p.save()`